# texturing - uv maps - seams - why did it unwrap this way?

Tags: texturing, uv

I thought I had marking seams down after I successfully predicted the outcome of all my seaming on all the primitive objects, including Suzanne, but I have just marked a seam and expected it to result in a separate island for the arm of my character but instead, it seems to have resulted in this...

[image: The map]
[image: illuminating the issue]

ps. I did have a clear image of the seam but I don't have the reputation for 3 links.

In case you can't see it clearly, there is a seam at his wrist, his shoulder then one going down the arm to unroll it.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a face inside the mesh, turn on display normals and look for the face inside the mesh and delete it, select mesh again and unwrap it